# Angular 2 app performance on Edge

Tags: javascript, performance, angular, microsoft-edge

I am new to angular development. I have a UI intensive Angular 2 web app with multiple, different types of charts and graphs, where data keeps on changing every 5 seconds. The app uses various 3rd party libraries ex: nvd3. The browser support is to be given on Chrome, Microsoft Edge, FF and Opera. We are experiencing poor performance on Edge compared to other browsers. We have been using profiler to detect possible memory leaks.
Any Edge specific pointers on performance improvement are requested.

Comment: Are you benchmarking an AoT build or dev?

Comment: If you're subscribing to a bunch of stuff, make sure you unsubscribe when you're done using them. Leaving a bunch of subscriptions laying around will slow things up. let subscriptions = []; subscriptions.push(someAction().subscribe(...));for(var i = 0; i < subscriptions.length; i++){ subscriptions[i].unsubscribe();}

Comment: @rick- This is against dev build.